# Java: Remote Method Invocation (RMI)

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to run simple RMI service, where server and client are on the same machine. Unfortunately, each time I try to ***run server class*** I get an exception. I keep server and client in seperate folders and I copied needed files to client.

These are the steps that I took:

1. Add Folder where server files are hold to CLASSPATH. 
   [image]
2. Start rmiregistry. (***As far as I know I no longer need to make stub file Updated with stub files***)
3. Run server. <- Exception
4. Run client.

Folder hierarchy:

server [AddServerIntf.class, AddServerImpl.class, AddServer.class]
client [AddServerIntf.class, AddClient.class]

**Exception**

```
C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\serwer>java AddServer
Exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AddServerIntf
```

**Code**

The remote interface

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
   double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Class which implements interface above**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject
   implements AddServerIntf {

   public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
   }
   public double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException {
      return d1 + d2;
   }
}
```

**Class which creates server**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddServer {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

      try {
         AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
         Naming.rebind("AddServer", addServerImpl);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
      }
   }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddClient {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
          String addServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/AddServer";
          AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(addServerURL);
         System.out.println("1st: " + args[1]);
         double d1 = Double.valueOf(args[1]).doubleValue();
         System.out.println("2nd: " + args[2]);

         double d2 = Double.valueOf(args[2]).doubleValue();
         System.out.println("Sum: " + addServerIntf.add(d1, d2));
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
      }
   }
}
```

**The effect with stub file is similar**

```
C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\serwer>java AddServer
Exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AddServerImpl_Stub
```

Comment: +1 for the details and formatting. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AddServerIntf, it seems you are having some classpath issues. Are you sure "stubs" are in classpath?

Comment: Insufficient detail. You need to show *complete* stack traces, not just the top bit.

Comment: @EJP That's all I got. I'll try to bring more details.

Comment: @Nambari At first I tried with stubs and I got an exception. Then I read that they are not needed - what I wrote above is without them.

Comment: It's not all you got. You got a complete stack trace showing line numbers. Post it, in the question, not as a comment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Registry doesn't have your remote interface on its CLASSPATH. IMHO the best solution to this is to run the Registry inside your server JVM, with LocateRegistry.createRegistry().

> As far as I know I no longer need to make stub file

Not correct. See the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject`. You would need to provide a `super(0)` line in your remote object's constructor to satisfy the conditions specified there.

Comment: Hmmm... ok I will make stub and run again.

Comment: Ok, So I've tried with stub and I got this `C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\serwer>java AddServer
Exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AddServerImpl_Stub`

Comment: So do what I said about super(0)!

Comment: Finally, it works! Sorry for misunderstanding, I'm a bit confused and tired. Thank YOU!